# wxPython - Play slider

Tags: python, slider, playback

I have a slider in the application and the panel on which are displayed something based on the value of the slider. I made a function (call by pressing button) that moves the slider by one increment at a time, but it does not work because the OnSliderDraw function is not called. Function is called when I move the slider manually, using the mouse, but I would like using PlaySlider function.

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.PlaySlider, id=xrc.XRCID("m_buttonPlay"))
self.Slider2 = xrc.XRCCTRL(self, "m_slider3")
self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.OnSliderDraw, id=xrc.XRCID("m_slider3"))

def OnSliderDraw(self, event):
.
.
. something
.
.

def PlaySlider(self, event):
    for i in range(0, self.Slider2.GetMax()):
        self.Slider2.SetValue(i+1)
        time.sleep(0.04)
```

Comment: Do you need the OnSliderDraw function? I believe this could be achieved by just calling self.Slider2.SetValue(i+1) in your PlaySlider event function, and before sleeping call wx.Yield() to update the UI.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how to call function with event from another function ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I believe the new edit might possibly be more what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to to is update the slider, try this:

```
## NOTE: This is untested
def SliderDrawer(self):
    for i in range(0,self.Slider2.GetMax()):
        self.Slider2.SetValue(i+1)
        wx.Yield() ## Added the Yield function
        time.sleep(0.1) ## Increased time so that visual can be seen

def PlaySlider(self,event):
    wx.CallAfter(self.SliderDrawer)
    event.Skip()
```

One of the issues you have is that you are not letting the User Interface update itself. While the event is going on there will be a lock in place until the event has finished.

This can be worked around by calling a separate function after the event. And within that separate function use wx.Yield() to allow the UI to update itself.

Also, if your SliderDraw function was going to do something else, you should include something more descriptive than ...something... because that something may be important ;)

***EDIT:***

If I may have misunderstood your question, and all you want to do is call the OnSlideDraw function, then you could use the idea of using wx.Yield() in your loop to see if it will be called, or modify OnSliderDraw to not be an event, but something that is called during your loop:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.PlaySlider, id=xrc.XRCID("m_buttonPlay"))
# Removed
#self.Slider2 = xrc.XRCCTRL(self, "m_slider3")
self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.OnSliderDraw, id=xrc.XRCID("m_slider3"))

def OnSliderDraw(self):
.
.
. something
.
.

def PlaySlider(self, event):
    for i in range(0, self.Slider2.GetMax()):
        self.Slider2.SetValue(i+1)
        self.OnSliderDraw()
        wx.Yield() # Added the Yield
        time.sleep(0.1) # Increased Time
    event.Skip() # It's important to finish the event with a Skip() to prevent any cross event phenomenon.
```

In your OnSliderDraw you can then do what you wanted to do without having to reference the event, and instead work directly with the widgets.

Comment: Yes, its worked when I create copy of OnSliderDraw function without event, and call it before wx.Yield(). But why event wx.EVT_SLIDER not working, if the slider is moved using the function, this is weird. 

Thanks for help xD

Comment: The wx.EVT_SLIDER wasn't being called because another event had control of the thread. This is a good thing, because it is easy to get yourself in an infinite loop of events, if let's say you had a user choose a value with either a text control or a slider, in which the slider would update the text control and vice versa. If there was no way for the event to lock out other events while it is running, your app would crash. This is because the slider would update the text control, and then the text control would update the slider, and so on and so on. Any way, no problem, and GOOD LUCK!